# Circular return - arrayTolist object JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to create the arrayToList object. Can someone please explain the difference between the following versions of the function?

```
function arrayToList(array) {
    var list = {};
    for(i=array.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        list.value = array[i];
        list.rest = list;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Then by calling the function I get:

```
console.log(arrayToList([1,2,3]))
```

=> `{ value: 1, rest: [Circular] }`

If after the for loop I use (THE CORRECT VERSION):
`list = { value: array[i], rest:list}`

```
console.log(arrayToList([1,2,3]))
```

=> `{ value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: {} } } }`

Can someone tell me the difference between using: `list.value = array[i]; list.rest = list;` vs `list = { value: array[i], rest:list}`?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `map` here?

Comment: @elclanrs: He means `list`

Comment: Had a look at the question marked duplicate, however that still doesn;t answer the q for me. The only line of answer that refers to it is: "You need to create multiple objects, define the object literal inside the loop body instead of assigning to the very same object over and over!"  

Isn't `list = { value: array[i], rest:list}` an assignment as well and when it hits `rest:list`, doesn't this do the same thing as `list.rest = list;` ?